# Git: How to make sure fixes are contained in newer versions?

Tags: git

Let's say I have both version 3 and 5 and 7 in production with different customers and meanwhile we're still developing features for version 8.

A bug is discovered in version 3, it is fixed and the version 3 customer(s) get a new version 3 (3.0.1 or whatever) with this hotfix.

Later a bug is discovered in version 5 by another customer and it too is fixed and a now we have to make a new hotfix release of version 5.

How do we make sure that this new version 5 (and indeed any future versions of version 5) contains all the fixes from previous versions?

Comment: That sounds like a job for testing and continuous integration much more than for a source code version control tool.

Comment: How so? Testing can't make sure that all the right commits from the fixes of version 3 are contained in the next version of version 5. Usually it means merging between branches or similar. But I am interested in knowing how others deal with this very common situation.

Comment: "The right commits ... contained in the next version" isn't what you test for, because it's 100% irrelevant.  You test the behavior of the software.  Either the new version 5 exhibits the bug, or it doesn't.  That is indeed a job for testing, as your assumption that the software will work correctly if it has the right commits included is invalid.

Comment: If you mean "major versions" 3, 5 and 7, you might not need to apply the fix from `3.0.1` - the code should be very different (maybe even incompatible) from one major version to another, and the bugs should not be equal...

Comment: Like back to the future, if you change the past, then you create an alternate future. You can't change version 3 and expect those changes to auto-propogate to versions 5 and 8 etc. You'd just have to merge the relevant bug fixes back in - if it's just one or two commits then a simple git cherry pick can solve all your problems without too much hassle. again it's very difficult to suggest fruitful advice without more clear specifications. HTH

Comment: You need to check the real code of the new version. A git commit is just a snapshot. Git itself cannot guarantee that the newest version contains the code that fixes a bug, even if the fix commit is included in the history of the newest commit. The fix commit's patch could be reverted by another commit. At last, only the test can prove the bug is fixed.

Comment: I must have been very unclear in my original post. This has nothing to do with testing. Of course, the result of incorporating a fix from an earlier version into a later version has to be tested. But that's not what I'm talking about. I am talking about "merging" (in the broadest possible sense) a fix/change/feature from an earlier production version to a later production version. Of course, given that the fix is relevant and compatible. In git, is it possible to cherry pick any commit from any branch to any other branch?

Comment: In our case, we're actually using TFS (TFVC) at the moment but we want to switch to git. I am just curious if it helps with some of these scenarios. For instance, in TFVC you can only merge to direct parent/children. That means that all production branches must have a common parent which all merges go through. Which means that this parent effectively becomes identical to the newest production branch. And it is wrong and causes problems to merge a v3 fix to v5 via what is effectively a v7 parent branch. It seems that you can merge directly from v3 to v5 in git, from what I read here.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have version_3, version_5, version_7 which represent as branches.

every fixed in version_3 should be merged by higher version.

e.g

switch first into branch version_5

> git checkout version_5

merge version_3 branch to version_5 branch

> git merged version_5

then do this again in version_7 or higher version.

You can also use GIT GUI to be able to manage git repo easily by using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)
or [GitExtensions](http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

more info on git : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

The answer to what you asked (how to "make sure" the bug is fixed) is to test every release, and not release new versions that exhibit known bugs.

What you're actually asking for is a process to ensure that the commit that fixed the bug in 3 will be included in any future releases of later versions.  While this may not be a bad idea, it does not ensure that the bug is fixed in those releases; that is still the responsibility of testing.  Even so, you at least would want to merge a new test case into every affected release version, and merging the fix from version 3 *is* a reasonable "first try" for fixing other versions, so some sort of merge pattern would be useful here.

There's really not a way to automate it, though.  You can take steps so that anyone following your workflow would naturally pick up the changes.  Anything that tries to be more thorough than that will likely involve a sweeping history rewrite - which will in turn impede efforts to support your existing install base.

So it comes down to this: You keep release branches so you can use them for subsequent releases in the same version line.  (If your workflow resembles gitflow, this probably points to a master merge commit.)  To start a hotfix you branch from the appropriate release branch.  The hotfix contains both a test case that would fail without the fix and pass with it, and the fix as applied to that version.  You merge that into every applicable release branch.

Comment: Everything you write is true, what I am talking about is that reasonable first try of merging the fix from one branch to another. Of course, after that you have to resolve conflicts, maybe doing considerable refactoring or even a rewrite of the fix. All this assuming the fix is necessary in this version, of course. And of course the result would be tested. I am not talking about automating the process. But it would be foolish if you make a fix in v3 not check if the fix is necessary in v5 and if so, foolish not to begin by merging the fix. Hand carrying the fix or ignoring it seems bad.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark Adelsberger's answer/comment, in that it's more a CI/testing/policy thing than a git specific thing. that said, I've had experience of a company that had a similar release strategy to yours, I'll try and briefly outline the way they did it:

If you had 3 released versions and one in develop:

```
v1
v2
v3
v4 (pre-release)
develop branch continues with changes for v4.
```

They had scenarios like:

```
Fix in v1 required only in v2 
    - Merge v1 -> v2
    - Fake merge v2 -> v3 (Take the only the state of the v3 branch so git doesn't report merge conflicts in future merges).
    - Fake merge v3 -> v4 (Take the only the state of the v4 branch so git doesn't report merge conflicts in future merges).

Fix in v1 required in all versions.
    - Merge v1 -> v2
    - Merge v2 -> v3
    - Massive code refactor in v3, fake merge into v4 (take v4 changes). 
    - Manually apply fix V4 changes.

Fix in v4 you want back ported to v2
    - Manually apply/cherry pick change into v2. 
    - Fake merge v2 -> v3 (Take the only the state of the v3 branch so git doesn't report merge conflicts in future merges).
    - Fake merge v3 -> v4 (Take the only the state of the v4 branch so git doesn't report merge conflicts in future merges).
```

It created a few headaches in that you end up doing a lot of testing on each branch anyway, because you'll still want to release tested software.
The merging was set up to cascade automatically, but clearly that wasn't always possible, so you often resorted to manual resolution.

It also leads to some battling about the scope of bugs/features, because you're often reluctant to spend potentially quite a long time resolving merge conflicts when the code has changed drastically.

You will get situations like the second one, where a portion of the code has undergone a complete refactor/moved entirely, so the fix no longer applies, or needs to be applied in a different way. You then need to perform these "fake merges" where you're essentially performing a merge with no changes to prevent future merge conflicts when simple changes are applied.

It is doable, and is manageable, but the conclusion this company came to was very quickly to start reducing the number of supported versions in the wild; or only apply very simple/critical fixes.

More anecdotal than a useful answer, but too long for a comment =D

Comment: I must have been very unclear in my original post. This has nothing to do with testing. Of course, the result of incorporating a fix from an earlier version into a later version has to be tested. But that's not what I'm talking about. I am talking about "merging" (in the broadest possible sense) a fix/change/feature from an earlier production version to a later production version. Of course, given that the fix is relevant and compatible. In git, is it possible to cherry pick any commit from any branch to any other branch?

Comment: Other than that, what you describe matches our experiences too. And of course, there is no way around these problems if you want to maintain several production versions, which we have to. You could ignore a fix made in version 3 and just let version 5 customers encounter the bug and fix it again, maybe in a different way by a different developer. But that seems like a bad idea. I am talking about always merging your fix to newer production branches, which might mean that your "merge" to a newer version is a total rewrite of that fix.

Comment: You can absolutely cherry pick any commit from any branch to any other branch. You can also cherry pick ranges of commits from any branch to any other branch. The process of cascading the merges into other branches can be automated. The success and ease of these operations will depend highly on the context of the changes.